# Why doesn't Dielectric placed in between increases the electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

[image]

Why should not The electric field due to the charge increase at P because of induced charge in the dielectric placed.
The induced positive charge will cause a more "more electric field effect" than "less electric field effect" of induced negative charge because it's at more distance.
Pls clarify.

Comment: Those negative charges in your drawing didn't just disappear. They still have an electric field too that cancels.

Comment: But I think the should have lesser effect as they are at more distance from P than positive charges

Comment: For the charges in the material to align the way you have drawn, the field lines from +Q need to end up at a -Q somewhere on the far side of P which would make them closer to P than the +Q is.

Comment: Wait but the field lines of +q have reduced at left side(near to +q) due to attraction by +q and equal and opp. Charge will appear at opposite side(near to P),how is negative charge present at opposite side(near to P)

Comment: I didn't get how the negative charge will appear closer to P(please note P is just a point on space not a charge,its just to give a reference to electric field on opposite side that I have named a point P)

Comment: Maybe you should just read up on what happens between capacitor plates. Basically, your drawing is incomplete. You can't have a die electric charged as you have shown without a negative charge somewhere on the right hand side of your drawing.

Comment: Please read about the topic a little more on Google. That might help correct your question.

Comment: Check out the Hyperphysics website for an explanation regarding dielectrics in capacitors